# Docker failed to initialize. Docker Desktop is shutting down

Tags: linux, windows, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run `Windows 11` and when I try to start `Docker desktop app` it gives me the following error: `Docker failed to initialize. Docker Desktop is shutting down.`

I have tried several thing before posting this:

1. Uninstalled `Docker desk app` and installed it again.
2. Uninstalled it, restarted the computer, updated `WSL 2` and installed the app again.

How can I fix it? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check out `docker/for-win` issues on W11 problems: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11805#issuecomment-922143312
This comment helped people, updating Hypervisor as well it seems: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12099#issuecomment-916276739

Comment: @tentative I tried some of the described ways from the source but the bug still was there, so I reinstalled entire system.

Answer (score 13):

Go to C drive , Users, Select your user, App data, Roaming and then delete the Docker folder. You shall be able to start docker again.

Comment: I had to delete the 'Docker Desktop' folder as well from AppData/Roaming

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the "delete settings.json" solutions and didn't work for me. This is what worked:

1. Open task manager
2. Type "docker"
3. kill it
4. reopen docker desktop

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also had to install/update WSL, via powershell command: wsl --update

Comment: This reminds me of an anecdote I personally heard from Ed Yourdon, the great S/W engineer, during a course: if you enter a restaurant and notice a cockroach on a wall, wthat do you think? (1) Oh, there is a cockroach in this restaurant; (2) Ouch, this restaurant is infested with cockroaches.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem too and already try
many solution found on the internet.

I have found [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12523#issuecomment-1029156833) and manually run C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.backend.exe, then I got this error.

```
[2022-07-23T13:14:00.191660000Z][com.docker.backend.exe][E] 
verifying docker scan plugin config: saving JSON: open 
<HOME>\.docker\scan\config.json: Access is denied.
[main.main()
[       common/cmd/com.docker.backend/main.go:96 +0x85
```

After removing '.docker/config.json' in C:\Users\{YOUR_USERNAME} folder, everything works fine after restarting docker desktop.

Hope my answer help.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve deleted %appdata%\Docker and %appdata%\Docker Desktop. After that everything is OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try by deleting the following folders-
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Docker
and C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop

It works for me.